# Paypal sandbox Firefox Issue

Tags: firefox, paypal, sandbox

I am using sandbox paypal. In Mozilla Firefox, once I complete the transaction , before getting redirected to return url page, the browser itself displays a message, asking for confirmation popup to continue further. If I click on the "continue" button immediately then things goes fine, but if I am not doing any action or click the continue button after 10 seconds, the page gets redirected automatically and I am not getting any of the variables posted from paypal. This kind of issue does not exist in Chrome and IE. Could any- body help me eliminating this issue for firefox?